# Map get with null key

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I'm confused by Kotlin's null safety features when it comes to maps. I have a `Map<String, String>`. Yet I can call `map.get(null)` and it returns `null` to indicate that the key is not present in the map. I expected a compiler error, because `map` is a `Map<String, String>` and not a `Map<String?, String>`. How come I can pass `null` for a `String` argument?

And a related question: is there any type of Map, be it a stdlib one or a third-party implementation, that may throw `NullPointerException` if I call `get(null)`? I'm wondering if it is safe to call `map.get(s)` instead of `s?.let { map.get(it) }`, for any valid implementation of `Map`.

**Update**

The compiler does indeed return an error with `map.get(null)`. But that is **not** because of null safety, but because the literal `null` doesn't give the compiler an indication of the type of the parameter being passed. My actual code is more like this:

```
val map: Map<String, String> = ...
val s: String? = null
val t = map.get(s)
```

The above compiles fine, and returns `null`. How come, when the key is supposed to be a `String` which is non-nullable?

Comment: I *do* get a compile time error if I do `map.get(null)` for a `Map<String, String>`. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: [Try it online here.](https://pl.kotl.in/nUzxC4uDE) `map.get(null)` doesn't compile.

Comment: @Sweeper sorry, the error is because `null` is a literal and so the compiler doesn't know what type it is. Try `map.get(null as String?)`.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Sweeper for clarification, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get.html) method in `Map` is declared like this:

```
abstract operator fun get(key: K): V?
```

so for a `Map<String, String>`, its `get` method should only take `String`s.

However, there is another [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get.html) extension function, with the receiver type of `Map<out K, V>`:

```
operator fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.get(key: K): V?
```

The covariant `out K` is what makes all the difference here. `Map<String, String>` is a kind of `Map<out String?, String>`, because `String` is a subtype of `String?`. As far as this `get` is concerned, a map with dogs as its keys "is a" map with animals as its keys.

```
val notNullableMap = mapOf("1" to "2")
// this compiles, showing that Map<String, String> is a kind of Map<out String?, String>
val nullableMap: Map<out String?, String> = notNullableMap
```

And this is why you can pass in a `String?` into `map.get`, where `map` is a `Map<String, String>`. The `map` gets treated as "a kind of" `Map<String?, String>` because of the covariant `out K`.

> And a related question: is there any type of Map, be it a stdlib one or a third-party implementation, that may throw NullPointerException if I call get(null)?

Yes, on the JVM, `TreeMap` (with a comparator that doesn't handle nulls) doesn't support null keys. Compare:

```
val map = TreeMap<Int, Int>()
println(map[null as Int?]) // exception!
```

and:

```
val map = TreeMap<Int, Int>(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
println(map[null as Int?]) // null
```

However, note that since the problematic `get` is an extension function that is available on every `Map`, you cannot prevent someone from passing in a nullable thing to your map *at compile time*, as long as your map implements `Map`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it well!

Comment: By the way, the answer to my related question "Is there any type of Map [...] that may throw NullPointerException if I call get(null)?" is actually "Yes". This is because the extension function simply calls `(this as Map<K, V>).get(key)` and the map implementation of "`this`" could well throw an exception, as per [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)): "Throws NullPointerException if the specified key is null and this map does not permit null keys"

Comment: @k314159 Huh, I don't know what I was thinking that day. I must have misread/misunderstood your question as asking about how to prevent this at compile time. A map that doesn't support null keys is easy to think of. See the edit.